# discord bot code using discord.py doesn't work at all

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I am currently just trying to make a bot for fun that will show up as online on the discord server. The version of python is past the required version need for discord.py and discord.py is installed, but whenever I put in code that from tutorial sites that should work, it always results in some really long error messages.

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='>')

@bot.command()
async def ping(ctx):
    await ctx.send('pong')

bot.run('token')
```

The code above should work but when I run it I get an error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 969, in _wrap_create_connection
    return await self._loop.create_connection(*args, **kwargs)  # type: ignore  # noqa
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/asyncio/base_events.py", line 1050, in create_connection
    transport, protocol = await self._create_connection_transport(
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/asyncio/base_events.py", line 1080, in _create_connection_transport
    await waiter
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/asyncio/sslproto.py", line 529, in data_received
    ssldata, appdata = self._sslpipe.feed_ssldata(data)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/asyncio/sslproto.py", line 189, in feed_ssldata
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/ssl.py", line 944, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1123)

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/johncalkins/Desktop/pythonscripts/altair/main.py", line 10, in <module>
    bot.run('token')
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 718, in run
    return future.result()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 697, in runner
    await self.start(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 660, in start
    await self.login(*args, bot=bot)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 509, in login
    await self.http.static_login(token.strip(), bot=bot)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/http.py", line 293, in static_login
    data = await self.request(Route('GET', '/users/@me'))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/http.py", line 185, in request
    async with self.__session.request(method, url, **kwargs) as r:
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aiohttp/client.py", line 1117, in __aenter__
    self._resp = await self._coro
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aiohttp/client.py", line 520, in _request
    conn = await self._connector.connect(
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 535, in connect
    proto = await self._create_connection(req, traces, timeout)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 892, in _create_connection
    _, proto = await self._create_direct_connection(req, traces, timeout)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 1051, in _create_direct_connection
    raise last_exc
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 1020, in _create_direct_connection
    transp, proto = await self._wrap_create_connection(
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 971, in _wrap_create_connection
    raise ClientConnectorCertificateError(req.connection_key, exc) from exc
aiohttp.client_exceptions.ClientConnectorCertificateError: Cannot connect to host discord.com:443 ssl:True [SSLCertVerificationError: (1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1123)')]
```

Due to me being a bit of an amateur I don't know what is going on. Is there anyone who can help me make sense of my situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve that issue you should navigate to your `Applications/Python 3.8/` folder and double click the `Install Certificates.command`.

This will install the SSL certificates that you are lacking.

[Source](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/issues/423#issuecomment-272093801)